# Markdown PDF doesn't convert correctly

Tags: markdown

I'm using VScode and trying to export PDF made with Markdown.

However, there are codes in the exported pdf file, such as `$` and `\int` etc.
I don't know why but headers `#` are displayed correctly.

How can I fix this?

Situation:

Write .md code in VScode

[image: VScode]

Export PDF with [MarkDown PDF](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf)

[image]

Exported PDF converts `#` but doesn't same about `$$`.

[image]

Comment: Normally, Markdown targets HTML. What tool are you using to build your PDF?

Comment: I'M using Markdown PDF. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are [a number of open issues](https://github.com/yzane/vscode-markdown-pdf/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+math) requesting first-class support for math in that extension, but at the moment it isn't supported out of the box.

There is [some evidence](https://github.com/yzane/vscode-markdown-pdf/issues/21#issuecomment-494048334) that you can append some HTML to your source Markdown document to get math to work, even in the PDF export:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$', '$']]}, messageStyle: "none" });
</script>
```

I'm not sure how that extension works internally, but [the "Install" section of its README](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf#install) says that "Installing Chromium" will appear in the status bar during installation, and [the "Special thanks" section](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzane.markdown-pdf#special-thanks) credits [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

That suggests that PDFs are generated from intermediate HTML. If that's the case, the MathJax snippet above would indeed have an opportunity to render math before the PDF is built.

Answer (score 0):

In addition,you could also use markdown preview enhanced extension, then get the html file,open it on Chrome or Edge and print it. It is a good way to keep latex expression show correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).